# Trouble adding directory rewrite to htaccess under wordpress

Tags: htaccess

I would like to add the following rewrite rule to htaccess, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to do it under wordpress.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(data|cache)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ redir.php?redir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My goal is to have any directory under root that doesn't currently exist to redirect to my file redir.php and pass the name of the nonexistent directory as a variable. The above code works, but existing directories are also being passed to the redir.php file as well.

I tried taking a look at the Wordpress Codex for rewrites but everything I've tried adding to functions.php seems to yield no new results, or instead of being sent to redir.php I get a wordpress 404 page.

Any ideas?? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with WordPress other than that a WP install is on the same server by coincidence? This looks like a general Apache HTAccess issue

Comment: Because htaccess is handled by Wordpress differently than just any other site.

Comment: No WP knowledge is required to answer the question, only Apache HTAccess knowledge

Comment: 50 bucks says I'll be told the opposite when I post this to stackoverflow

Comment: It's wrong to say, "htaccess is handled by Wordpress differently", but at the same time this is not a "general Apache HTAccess issue" either. WP makes use of a _front-controller_ pattern (as many sites do). It is this "front-controller" that is your "problem" here. As [I answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48757742/369434) you can't do something like this in `.htaccess`, because of the _front-controller_, not strictly WP. You will need to solve this in WP, not `.htaccess`. And how you do this is specific to WordPress.

Comment: (You could perhaps re-ask your question, but remove the `.htaccess` aspect?)

Comment: Thanks, MrWhite, you just earned me 50 bucks. From my perspective, this was a good starting point. I will extend this and see what @Tom J Nowell thinks.

Comment: @zoltar WP knowledge on its own couldn't have answered that, you needed Apache knowledge to know about front controllers. Also keep in mind that in WP rewrite rules are a very different thing, the rewrite rule API maps URLs on to query variables for `WP_Query`, it can't be used to redirect execution on to another file such as `redir.php`. Without knowing what the context/purpose of `redir.php` is it's difficult to recommend something, eitherway you asked an Apache `.htaccess` question and got an answer elsewhere

Comment: I recommend you mark the answer MrWhite wrote as correct, what you want to do can't be done due to Apache limitations. Then, ask a new question that explains your original problem that `redir.php` tries to solve, looking for a WP based solution. It may well be that the `/data/` and `/cache` URLs being used are completely unnecessary, but without surrounding context that's difficult to determine

Comment: @Tom J Nowell I will do what you recommend, but hooweee this is a lot of runaround for what I originally thought was a simple question anyone with experience in htaccess redirects and Wordpress could answer LOL  guess that was wishful thinking on my part... Although, I'm still confused as to whether I should post my new question on stackoverflow or wordpress

Comment: Post the new one on WP, the new one isn't an Apache question

Comment: Alas, simply handling 404s was the ultimate way to go, so I accepted MrWhite's answer on SO. Thanks for clearing all this up for me, guys!